# Including Typescript code in Relay (System.js import)

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs, relay

How to include system.js to fix the error below? Or is there any other solution?

I downloaded the relay-starter-kit (https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit), changed the database.js to database.ts with the below content (Snippet 1).

I ran "npm run update-schema" and got the error

```
System.register([], function (exports_1) {
^

ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (database.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
..
```

I know it occurs because update-schema uses scripts/updateSchema.js -> data/schema.js -> which imports objects from data/database.js (compiled version of database.ts) has -

```
System.register([], function(exports_1) {
```

Snippet 1:

```
/// <reference path="./interface.d.ts" />

export class User implements IUser{
    constructor (public id: String, public name: String){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
// Model types
class UserModel extends User implements IUserModel {

     constructor(public id: String, public name: String){
         super (id,name);
     }
     getUser ():IUser{
         return this;
     }
     setUser (_User:IUser) : void {
         this.id = _User.id;
         this.name = _User.name;
     }  
    getUserbyId (_id:String):IUser{
        if (_id === this.id){
            return this;
        } else {
            return null;
        }    
    }  

}

export class Widget implements IWidget{
    constructor (public id: String, public name: String){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
// Model types
class WidgetModel extends Widget implements IWidgetModel {

     constructor(public id: String, public name: String){
         super (id,name);
     }
     getWidget ():IWidget{
         return this;
     }
     setWidget (_Widget:IWidget) : void {
         this.id = _Widget.id;
         this.name = _Widget.name;
     }
    getWidgetbyId (_id:String):IWidget{
        if (_id === this.id){
            return this;
        } else {
            return null;
        }    
    }       
}

// Mock data
var viewer:IUserModel = new UserModel('1','Anonymous');

var widgets:IWidget[] = ['What\'s-it', 'Who\'s-it', 'How\'s-it'].map((name:String, i:any) => {
  let widget:IWidgetModel = new WidgetModel(name,`${i}`);
  return widget;
});
  export function getUser (_id:String):IUser {
          return viewer.getUserbyId(_id);
  } 
  export function getViewer ():IUser {
      return viewer.getUser();
  }
  export function getWidget (_id:String):any {
      widgets.forEach(
          w => {
              if (w.id === _id) 
                  return w;
              else 
                  return null;
          }
      );
  }
  export function getWidgets (): IWidget[]{
      return widgets;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tsconfig.json had

"module": "system",

Changed it to

"module": "umd",

and it worked.